# loops binary tree in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I create a binary tree and now I would like to display the result in my jsp with conditions.

Each node has 4 elements (id, question, answer, and leftnode rightnode)

If the user clicks "Yes", the program goes to the left of the tree and if he answers "no" to the right of the tree.

For example, the initial question is "you're a man?" If he answers "yes" we will go to the left and page view "you're a singer?" If he answers "no" page displays "you're French? ".

In java, it would to the original question.

```
cursor [i]. GetQuestion ()
```

Then For yes

```
cursor [i] getQuestion. GetLeftnode ()
```

and for no

```
cursor [i]. GetRightnode (). GetQuestion
```

Until the, everything works normally, but when I want to loop until there is no longer any issue by

```
<c:when test="${not empty cursor[i].getQuestion() }">
```

the program stops at the first loop and stops it that cursor is not empty

here is my complete code jstl

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${not empty cursor[i].getQuestion() }">
      <c:if test="${param.btn eq 'Oui'}" var="oui">
         <c:set var="cursor" value="${cursor[i].getLeftnode() }" scope="session"></c:set>
         <c:set var="i" value="${i+1 }" scope="session"></c:set>
      </c:if>
      <c:if test="${param.btn eq 'Non'}" var="non">
         <c:set var="cursor" value="${cursor[i].getRightnode() }" scope="session"></c:set>
     <c:set var="i" value="${i+1 }" scope="session"></c:set>
      </c:if>
   </c:when>
</c:choose>

<c:out value="${cursor.getQuestion() }"></c:out>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using methods like `${cursor.getQuestion() }` you have to use property names like this: `${cursor.question }`

P.S. And make sure you have a proper getter names (get should be lower case)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. 
I found the solution. For those who are interested, here is the code that works

```
<c:set var="cursor" value="${nodes }" scope="application"></c:set>      <form method="get">
      <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${not empty cursor.getQuestion() }">
         <c:if test="${param.btn eq 'yes'}" var="yes">
        <c:set var="cursor" value="${cursor.getLeftnode() }" scope="session"></c:set>
         </c:if>
         <c:if test="${param.btn eq 'no'}" var="no">
        <c:set var="cursor" value="${cursor.getRightnode() }" scope="session"></c:set>
         </c:if>
      </c:when>
      </c:choose>
      <c:out value="${cursor.getQuestion() }"></c:out>
```

The problem was scope. At each loop, with "session" scoped my variable was reset each time. By "application" in scope, it is initialized only once and I can get what I want

Thank